# How do you enable popups on custom objects?

Tags: popup

What do I need to setup in order to display a popup for a custom object? Here is an example of a popup for a contact. Where can I see these settings in Salesforce?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Setup -> Develop -> Custom Objects
2. Find the object and click on it
3. Click edit next to the page layout of your choice
4. In the page layout editor, click on "mini page layout"

There is where you can edit which fields appear on the pop-up

If you want the same pop-up on a vf page you have to use the outputField tag for the Lookup field. You can also potentially roll your own using hacks / code for the standard field output

Comment: I am guessing that the popup does not work if I want to have it over an item in a related list.

Comment: @abhi - Not using the standard UI no.